# Query for adding columns based on a matching value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables: keys and orders

In the **key** table, I have *order id* only, but I require more details which are available on the **orders** table, like *emails, names*.. etc.

How can I append the keys that have a matching *order id* to the other table?

Keys Table

```
Key          Order ID
-----        --------
1234         0001
1235         0001
1532         0002
1602         0003
1802         0004
```

Orders Table

```
Email                   Order ID
-----                   --------
email1@example.com         0001
email1@example.com         0001
email2@example.com         0002
email3@example.com         0003
email4@example.com         0004
```

Required Result:

```
Email                   Order ID       Key
-----                   --------     -------
email1@example.com         0001       1234
email1@example.com         0001       1235
email2@example.com         0002       1532
email3@example.com         0003       1602
email4@example.com         0004       1802
```

Comment: Read about join.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `join` should do the trick:

```
SELECT `email`, o.`order_id`, `key`
FROM   `orders` o
JOIN   `keys k ON o.`order_id` = k.`order_id`
```

If it's possible to have an order without a key, you should use `left join` instead of `join`.

Comment: This will produce four rows for email `email1@example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate the values in each table to avoid a Cartesian product on the orders.  In MySQL v8, you can use `row_number()`.  This answer shows what to do in the earlier versions.

```
select o.*, k.key
from (select o.*,
             (@rno := if(@o = order_id, @rno + 1,
                         if(@o := order_id, 1, 1)
                        )
             ) as seqnum
      from (select o.*
            from orders o
            order by order_id
           ) o cross join
           (select @o := -1, @rno := 0) params
     ) o join
     (select k.*,
             (@rn, := if(@o = order_id, @rn, + 1,
                         if(@o := order_id, 1, 1)
                        )
             ) as seqnum
      from (select k.*
            from keys k
            order by order_id
           ) k cross join
           (select @o := -1, @rnk := 0) params
     ) k
     on o.order_id = k.order_id and o.seqnum = k.seqnum;
```

By comparison, the code in MySQL 8+ or almost any other database looks like this:

select o.*, k.key
from (select o.*, row_number() over (partition by order_id order by order_id) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
     (select k.*, row_number() over (partition by order_id, order by order_id) as seqnum
      from keys k
     ) k
     on o.order_id = k.order_id and o.seqnum = k.seqnum;

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a table valued SQL Function and use in the query.

```
CREATE FUNCTION TEST (@key varchar(20))
RETURNS @Order TABLE   -- Table definition for result
   (
      Email varchar(100),
      Name varchar(100)
   )
AS
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO @Order
SELECT TOP 1 EMAIL,Name FROM Order WHERE OrderId = @key

RETURN

END
```

Then in your Select query retrieve the result like this :

```
SELECT *,(SELECT Email From Dbo.Test(K.OrderId)) FROM KEYS K
```